# New Ubuntu 20.04 Desktop System. Freezing after idle. Suspect Suspend and won't wake up

Tags: 20.04, suspend, wakeup

I've recently loaded Ubuntu onto my desktop.  I had been using Windows 10 before.

Now the system seems to go to sleep and I am not able to wake it up.  I've taking the recommended steps that I have found to disable suspend/sleep/hibernate on my system, but it still seems to do this sometimes.  Sometimes this will happen after just 20 minutes and other times it won't do it for days on end.

My system is running Ubuntu 20.04 LTX x86_64
on a Gigabyte AB350-Gaming 3 Motherboard with a Ryzen 5 1600 3.2 GHz processor NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1060 3GB Video Card and 16 GB of memory.

I am not sure what to do next.

Comment: Do you see any messages in `/var/log/syslog` around the time the computer goes to sleep (or wakes up) that might suggest an issue?

Comment: Nothing that stood out to me.  Most suggested looking at dmesg only issue I see in there is a failure to assign memory to pci devices that don't appear to exist which seems like you can ignore if you don't have devices at those slots.  What would a power issue look like in that log file?

Comment: Issue's gotten worse.  Back on Windows for now.  I do see lines like this showing up now.

 ata2.00: exception Emask 0x11 SAct 0xd9 SErr 0x400000 action 0x6 frozen
 ata2.00: irq_stat 0x48000008, interface fatal error
ata2: SError: { Handshk }
ata2.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED